# Japanese input control

Tags: uitextfield, cjk, uitextinput

I have the following issue, concerning the way to fine control Japanese input in an iOS app. To make things clear I include an image to this post (see below).

As one can see I have typed や in the input text field and a bunch of choices (や 役 矢 訳 ヤ 屋 焼き …) appear above the keyboard for possible conversions.

Here is what I would like to know:
The choices presented in the picture make no sense for my particular app. I would like to be able to set myself the possible conversions offered to the user.
In this case it would be (山形県 山口県 山梨県). Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

In other words I am trying to find out how handle the set of data appearing above the keyboard.

Thanks in advance for any relevant information.

[image]

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but I don't think you have access to this information.  If you want a custom list, you will probably have to make your own keyboard.  Even then...what do you plan to do?  Make a list of every city and town in Japan?  God help you if you forget one...

Comment: Is the question about how to manipulate the dictionary of this existing input application, or about how to make a new one that is optimized for geographical queries? In the former case, the answer is likely to be "contact the creator of the existing one", but in the latter case, that's certainly possible.

Comment: @borrrden If indeed you need a list of geopgraphical entities for Japan, best download it from the Japan post office: http://www.post.japanpost.jp/zipcode/download.html. This is very comprehensive. Getting a list of station names (which are often referred to by people instead of the proper block/town/city names) shouldn't be a problem either, and if then still something is missing, it won't be the end of the world. There are lots of words missing in existing input methods, too.